# How to take back local notification after being displayed?

Tags: ios, lockscreen, localnotification

Set the scene: Its 7:55 AM. Sets local notification for 8:01 AM. Pops up on lock screen at 8:01 AM. User ignores it.

Would it be possible to take back that notification at lets say 8:07?

In Knock, the app that lets you unlock your macbook with a nock does this. It shows “knock twice to unlock on the lock screen. When you knock, it disappears. How is this done?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652274/dismiss-an-already-delivered-uilocalnotification

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You call `-cancelLocationNotification` on `UIApplication` passing to it the local notification instance you want to cancel.

Check the docs:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html

... and

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/cancelLocalNotification:

Also see:

[Can I dismiss the local notification when next time the app launch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618345/can-i-dismiss-the-local-notification-when-next-time-the-app-launch)

[Dismiss local notifications when application becomes active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841982/dismiss-local-notifications-when-application-becomes-active)